# Twig macro in external file

Tags: symfony, twig

I have three pages that uses the same macro. I put the same portion of code in the top of all three pages. Can I put this macro in external file and reuse it?

Here the macro:

```
{% macro generateMenu(item) %}
    <li>
        <h4>
            <a class="{{ item.class }}" href="{{ item.link }}">
                {{ item.label }}
            </a>
        </h4>
    </li>
{% endmacro %}
```

Calling the macro:

```
<ul class="">
    {% for item in Menu %}
        {{ _self.generateMenu(item) }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In fact, there are some variations, I will use some parameters. But the focus is: I want to put this macro in a external file to reuse code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documentation states: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/import.html

Define macro in external file and import it in each of your files that use it:

```
{% import 'external.file.here' as something %}

{{ something.macro_in_that_file(some, params) }}
```